# How corner atom of a cube is shared by 8 atoms?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, geometry, crystals

> *Since each atom is at the corner of a cube and 8 cubes meet at each corner. Therefore each atom is shared by 8 cubes.*

But I don't visualize it, so please tell how I Visualize it.

Comment: This is a question in 'solid-state-chemistry'. Anyways, it is not researched enough.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic: insufficient prior research

Answer (score 3):

[Count:](http://www.mikeblaber.org/oldwine/chm1045/notes/Forces/Solids/Forces07.htm)

[image: cubic lattice]

the central blue dot is shared by eight unit lattices.